# WAL archiving in postgres is not working

Tags: postgresql, wal

I have enabled WAL archiving in postgres configuration file. When I restarted Postgres service WAL recovery is not working. There was no wal recovery entries in logs.

#### Steps I followed:

```
Created directory for wal:
mkdir -p  /var/lib/pgsql/wals/
mkdir -p  /var/lib/pgsql/backups/
chown postgres:postgres -R /var/lib/pgsql/backups/
chown postgres:postgres -R /var/lib/pgsql/wals/

Edited the postgresql.conf with the below changes:
wal_level=archive
archive_mode=on
archive_command = 'test ! -f /var/lib/pgsql/wals/%f && cp %p /var/lib/pgsql/wals/%f'

sudo service postgresql restart 10
sudo su - postgres
pg_basebackup -D /var/lib/pgsql/data #created base backup
tar -C /var/lib/pgsql/data/ -czvf /var/lib/pgsql/backups/pg_basebackup_backup.tar.gz .
```

#### Deleted two rows of data in my database and stopped the postgres service

```
sudo service postgresql stop 10
```

#### Extracted the Basebackup

```
tar xvf /var/lib/pgsql/backups/pg_basebackup_backup.tar.gz -C /var/lib/pgsql/data
```

#### Created recovery.conf with the below content and restarted postgres service

```
echo "restore_command = 'cp /var/lib/pgsql/wals/%f %p'">/var/lib/pgsql/recovery.conf
cp /var/lib/pgsql/recovery.conf /var/lib/pgsql/data/
sudo service postgresql stop 10
sudo service postgresql start 10
```

There was no wal recovery entries in logs and the two rows which I deleted didn't get restored.

Comment: the first thing coming: $PGDATA is `/usr/local/pgsql/data`, so I would expect wals directory to be `/usr/local/pgsql/data/pg_wal`.. did you create  a symbolic link to there from `/var/lib/pgsql/wals/`?..

Comment: I changed its location and restarted postgres service but still no wal recovery entries in logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pg_basebackup can catch all WAL segments during backup. I use basebackup into tar format with "-X stream" option and all works well. See here - [pg_basebackup – bash script for backup and archiving on Google storage](http://postgresql.freeideas.cz/pg_basebackup-bash-script-backup-archiving-google-storage/)
It works excellent - I backup database 4.5+ TB big which takes almost 2 days.

Restoration is described here - [pg_basebackup / pg-barman – restore tar backup](http://postgresql.freeideas.cz/pg_basebackup-pgbarman-restore-tar-backup/)

All works - we already had incidents when we had to restore from these backups.

Comment: I will try and let you know if any problem occurs

Comment: I wanted continuous archiving of logs,whenever new data is being inserted WAL log should be created so that if postgres db crashes we can restore to previous stable state

Comment: In that case you need pg-barman. This can archive WAL logs continuously - http://docs.pgbarman.org/release/2.3/#wal-streaming
We use it too I will add some comments about it...

Comment: I checked our implementation and everything is described in pg-barman manual. You need to create users (barman and streaming_barman) and allow replication slots and wal senders on db (allowed by default on pg 10) and set config file for given server on barman. Barman simply starts "/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_receivewal" and collects all WAL log automatically - between backups. Old WALs are deleted autom. when you make new backup - i.e. new PIT for barman. Works like charm.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The WAL containing the two deleted rows probably hasn't been archived yet.

`archive_command` is run whenever a 16 MB WAL segment is full or something forces a log switch.

To be able to recover the latest changes that have not been archived yet, you have to copy the contents of `pg_wal` to the `pg_wal` directory in the restored base backup.

You can also consider streaming replication or `pg_receivewal` if you cannot afford to lose transactions.